# How to apply semi-transparent white color to outline of circle wipe

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transparency, blur, hlsl

A goal for this question is that outline of my circle wipe improves like left exmple in the image below. So far outline of my circle wipe does not have two clear semi-transparent rings. If you know how to render them like the left image, would you give me some advice?

An ideal circle wipe I would like to implement.

[Ideal circle wipe video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/nk8qDyt5R3U)

Here's the shader I use.

```
Shader "Unlit/CircleWipe"
 {
     Properties
     {
         _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
         _FadeTex("Fade Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
         _Radius("Wipe Radius", Float) = 0
         _Horizontal("Horizontal ratio", Float) = 1
         _Vertical("Vertical ratio", Float) = 1
         _RadiusSpeed("Radius Speed", Float) = 1
         _CenterX("Center X",  Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.5
         _CenterY("Center Y",  Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.5
         [HDR]_FadeColour("Fade Colour", Color) = (1,1,1,0)
         _Offset("Offset", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
     }
     SubShader
     {
         Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent" }
         Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha


     Pass
     {
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag
         #pragma multi_compile_fog

         #include "UnityCG.cginc"

         struct appdata
         {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
             float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         struct v2f
         {
             float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
             UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
             float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
         };

         sampler2D _MainTex;
         sampler2D _FadeTex;
         float4 _MainTex_ST;
         float _Radius;
         float _Horizontal;
         float _Vertical;
         float _RadiusSpeed;
         float _CenterX;
         float _CenterY;
         fixed4 _FadeColour : COLOR;
         float4 _Offset;

         v2f vert (appdata v)
         {
             v2f o;
             o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
             o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
             UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
             return o;
         }

         fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
         {
             fixed4 topCol = tex2D(_MainTex , i.uv);
             fixed4 fadeCol = _FadeColour * tex2D(_FadeTex , i.uv);
             float2 center = float2(_CenterX , _CenterY);
             float2 pos = i.uv.xy;
             float dist = length((pos - center) * float2(_Vertical , _Horizontal));
             return lerp(fadeCol , topCol , smoothstep(_Radius , _Radius + 1.1 , dist));
         }
         ENDCG
     }
 }
 }
```

Comparison

[image: Comparison]

Environment
Unity2020.3f
Project type: Universal render pipeline
Target: IOS & Android

Comment: Please don't make breaking edits to your question after you receive an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float a = smoothstep(_Radius - 1.1, _Radius, dist);
float b = smoothstep(_Radius, _Radius + 1.1, dist);
float t = a - b;
fixed4 col = lerp(fadeCol , topCol , b);
return lerp(col, _FadeColour, t);
```

You may also try to replace the last line with:

```
return col + _FadeColour * t;
```

---

Effect achieved with 2 pictures:

[image: Effect with 2 pics]
[image: Without the circle]
[image: Large circle]

Comment: Thanks to your advice, white color of outline has become much clearer. I thank you a lot! Because a goal for this question is to add clear semi-transparent rings to the outline like the ideal exapmple does - shared in the image and the video link above, if there is any further problematic aspect in my shader script, would you point out so that the shader can get closer to the ideal exmple?

Comment: The circle in the video isn't generated by shader, it's an image over the background, because you could see it gets hazier and wider when it grows.

Comment: You really helped me with your wisdom. I so appreciate you. You made me realised that range of my knowledge is not sufficient enough. Thank you for giving me very helpful eye-opening advice. Thanks to you, I suceeded in implementing my ideal circle wipe.